# Knockout.js post back to server to update model

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I know for a fact that you can create 2 way bindings in knockout.js. This changes the model in javascript once you change the view and the opposite. I need a way to notify and send this changes back to the server. So I pretty much need to do a post to the server. How can I do this?

What I mean by this, is that I somehow need to attach an event handler so whenever I change once of my models it automatically posts back to the server the changes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.value1 = ko.observable();
    self.value2 = ko.observable();
    ko.computed(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/path/to/server/endpoint',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                value1: self.value1(),
                value2: self.value2()
            }
        });
    });
}
```

You should not need individual "manual subscriptions" for each viewmodel property. Just define a `ko.computed`. All `ko.computed`s are automatically notified of changes to the observables that they depend on. In the code above, the computed depends on the value1 and value2 observables (in the `data` argument to the jQuery `$.ajax` function). Whenever the value of an observable changes, the wrapped `ko.computed` function will execute, and submit the new value(s) to the server.

Comment: This works - almost. It seems to post as soon as the page loads the first time. Any way to prevent that happening the first time?

Comment: I found a way around the first load.
`function MyViewModel(){self.firstload=true;ko.computed(function{self.value1();if(firstload)return firstload=false;$.post("/path/to/endpoint",{data: self.value1();});}}}` (use http://jsbeautifier.org/ :P)

Answer (score 1):

How about a [manual subscription](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/reacting-to-changes-in-knockoutjs.html)?

> - Manual subscriptions can be thought of like bindings for your view model. Bindings allow your UI to react to changes in your view model, while manual subscriptions allow your view model to react to changes to itself. This may mean making updates to other related objects in your view model.
> - A common example is triggering an update to an observable via AJAX when another observable changes, such as when a checkbox is checked or a dropdown value is changed. In this case, the manual subscription acts like an asynchronous computed observable.

Answer (score 0):

I do it via json (only one way):

load your ko binding from json String (example):

```
userSettingsModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON('${userSettingsJSON}');
    ko.applyBindings(userSettingsModel);
```

Send the changed ko Object back to server (example):

```
function saveConferencesFilter() {
    // console.log(ko.mapping.toJSON(userSettingsModel));
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: '/AudioPlace/userSettings/rest',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        data: ko.mapping.toJSON(userSettingsModel),
        success: function (data) {
            getConferences();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Well, I am sorry for formulating this incorrectly but I need to automatically send the changes back to the server without the end user doing anything else than changing the view. I just need a way to add some custom code once a property was changed in my model.

Comment: it's fine. I already guess on writing the answer it's possible not your are looking for. But the marked answer is the goal.